# Shopify API: Create hidden product variant

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to create an unpublished/hidden product variant through the Shopify API?  I know it's possible to create a hidden product by specifying `product['published'] = false` in the POST request, but I just want to create a hidden *variant* that can be added to a cart.

What I'm attempting to do is create a "sale" item that's only available to a single user with a specific cart.  I can create the product variant through node.js, and I can use AJAX to actually add the product to the cart on the client side, but I'll never have access to the shop's dashboard so I can't mask product variants through collections, linked options, et cetera.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not possible to hide a particular variant at the API level, but you can do it via Liquid or client-side code.

Take a look at how http://apps.shopify.com/quantity-breaks implements this and you should have a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

(Whoops!  Trigger-happy on the 'return' key...)  I'll take a look at the app!

Comment: Just a quick question -- if I were to use only client-side code (id est, no Liquid) to hide a variant, what would be the best way to identify it as hidden?  Adding metafields?

Comment: That sounds good. I haven’t done it before, but metafields would be perfect for this. You might want to ping the Shappify guys about their experience as they’re pretty friendly.

Comment: Okey dokey.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: where you able to implement it ?? I also need this kind of solution. pls check https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/update-cart-total-with-discount-via-api-220450